# MSBuild - Copy All Bin Output - Debug|Release

Tags: .net, msbuild, build-script

I have the following MSBuild targets file (below).

How would I add an additional step after Default to copy all the `\bin\Debug` or `\bin\Release` from one of the projects to a folder called  `binaries` that is in the same folder as the `.targets` file was run?

If I could get it to be smart about if it uses Debug or Release even better.

**UPDATE**: I have updated my code that I have gotten so far. Still would be nice to be able to run the .bat file that kicks this msbuild off in two operating modes: Release and Debug and then have two different folders in the Binaries folder

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <SolutionFiles Include=".\**\*.sln"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DebugBinFiles Include=".\src\Sample.Core\Sample.Core.Infrastructure\bin\Debug\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ReleaseBinFiles Include=".\src\Sample.Core\Sample.Core.Infrastructure\bin\Release\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Default" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFiles)" Condition=""/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(BinFiles)" DestinationFolder=".\binaries\Debug" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define in your targets file `Configuration` property default value
2. Use this property value in a output path
3. Instead of `AfterTargets` use `DependsOnTargets`, but as Default target define the last one, so targets will execute in the same order but just chained in reverse order
4. Save XML below as `final.targets` or how would you like name it
5. Run in command line msbuild `final.targets /p:Configuration=RELEASE` for release configuration build

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         DefaultTargets="CopyBinOutput">

   <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- define defaults -->
      <Configuration Condition="$(Configuration)==''">DEBUG</Configuration>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Choose>
      <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='DEBUG' ">
         <ItemGroup>
            <BinFiles Include=".\src\Sample.Core\Sample.Core.Infrastructure\bin\Debug\**\*.*" />
         </ItemGroup>
      </When>

      <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='RELEASE' ">
         <ItemGroup>
           <BinFiles Include=".\src\Sample.Core\Sample.Core.Infrastructure\bin\Release\**\*.*"/>
          </ItemGroup>
      </When>
  </Choose>

  <Target Name="EntryPointTarget">
      <Message Text="EntryPointTarget started" />
      <!-- here is build your solution -->
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CopyBinOutput" DependsOnTargets="EntryPointTarget">
      <Message Text="CopyBinOutput started" />
     <Copy SkipUnchangedFiles="True" OverWriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
           SourceFiles="@(BinFiles)" 
           DestinationFiles="@(BinFiles->'.\binaries\$(Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />

      <Message Text="CopyBinOutput finished, destination is .\binaries\$(Configuration)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```